# Issue with mobile navigation pushing logo and hamburger button up

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I'm currently working on a responsive navbar for a website, and I'm facing an issue where the logo and hamburger button get pushed up when the mobile navigation menu is activated. (I am using NextJS and TailwindCSS btw)

Here's the code:

```js
"use client";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";

const Navbar = () => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);

  function toggleNav() {
    setActive(!active);
  }

  return (
    <div className="bg-gray-800">
      <div className="max-w-7xl px-6 h-24 m-auto items-center flex justify-between flex-wrap md:flex-nowrap">
        {/* Logo */}
        <div className="flex flex-col flex-1">
          <p className="text-white font-black text-3xl">NSTK</p>
        </div>

        {/* Hamburger Menu */}
        <div
          className="hamburger-menu md:hidden block space-y-1"
          onClick={toggleNav}
        >
          <div className="h-1 w-6 bg-white rounded-lg"></div>
          <div className="h-1 w-6 bg-white rounded-lg"></div>
          <div className="h-1 w-6 bg-white rounded-lg"></div>
        </div>

        {/* List */}
        <div
          className={
            active
              ? "flex flex-col md:flex-row space-y-4 md:space-y-0 md:space-x-4 bg-gray-800 w-screen p-5 transform-y-0"
              : "hidden md:flex md:flex-row md:space-y-0 md:space-x-4"
          }
        >
          <Link href={"/"}>
            <p className="text-white/80 hover:text-white/90 transition-all duration-300">
              Home
            </p>
          </Link>
          <Link href={"/"}>
            <p className="text-white/80 hover:text-white/90 transition-all duration-300">
              Home
            </p>
          </Link>
          <Link href={"/"}>
            <p className="text-white/80 hover:text-white/90 transition-all duration-300">
              Home
            </p>
          </Link>
          <Link href={"/"}>
            <p className="text-white/80 hover:text-white/90 transition-all duration-300">
              Home
            </p>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

Images that might be relevant:
[How it looks when the Navbar is closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AHQI.png)
[How it looks when the Navbar is activated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2S7v.png)

Sorry if this question is not perfectly written, this is my first post on Stackoverflow.

I have tried using flex-wrap for it to put the navbar in a separate line on mobile-devices, but it doesn't seem to work as expected. When noticing that it pushes the other 2 divs up, I have tried giving it a margin-top, as I thought the margins might cause the problem, that didn't solve it either. So now I am hoping to get the solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have fixed height in parent div with `h-24` class, when you open nav on mobile, it tries to squeeze content.

You can change this to `md:h-24`, so the height will be `auto` on smaller screen.

```
"use client";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";

export default function IndexPage() {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);

  function toggleNav() {
    console.log("toggleNav");
    setActive(!active);
  }
  return (
    <div className="bg-gray-800">
      <div className="max-w-7xl px-6 md:h-24 h-auto m-auto items-center flex justify-between flex-wrap md:flex-nowrap">
        {/* Logo */}
        <div className="flex flex-col flex-1 py-4">
          <p className="text-white font-black text-3xl">NSTK</p>
        </div>

        {/* Hamburger Menu */}
        <div
          className="hamburger-menu md:hidden block space-y-1"
          onClick={toggleNav}
        >
          <div className="h-1 w-6 bg-white rounded-lg"></div>
          <div className="h-1 w-6 bg-white rounded-lg"></div>
          <div className="h-1 w-6 bg-white rounded-lg"></div>
        </div>

        {/* List */}
        <div
          className={
            active
              ? "flex flex-col md:flex-row space-y-4 md:space-y-0 md:space-x-4 bg-gray-800 w-screen p-5 transform-y-0"
              : "hidden md:flex md:flex-row md:space-y-0 md:space-x-4"
          }
        >
          <Link href={"/"}>
            <p className="text-white/80 hover:text-white/90 transition-all duration-300">
              Home
            </p>
          </Link>
          <Link href={"/"}>
            <p className="text-white/80 hover:text-white/90 transition-all duration-300">
              Home
            </p>
          </Link>
          <Link href={"/"}>
            <p className="text-white/80 hover:text-white/90 transition-all duration-300">
              Home
            </p>
          </Link>
          <Link href={"/"}>
            <p className="text-white/80 hover:text-white/90 transition-all duration-300">
              Home
            </p>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the [codesanbox link](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/xenodochial-lehmann-glf0ud?welcome=true) and [preview link](https://glf0ud-3000.csb.app/).

Comment: Hi, thanks! I have just removed the fixed height, and put in a p-8. Kind of similar to your solution. Works perfectly fine for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try taking the list div out of the navbar div:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";

const Navbar = () => {
    const [active, setActive] = useState(false);

    function toggleNav() {
        setActive(!active);
    }

    return (
        <div className="bg-gray-800">
            <div className="max-w-7xl px-6 h-24 m-auto items-center flex justify-between flex-wrap md:flex-nowrap">
                {/* Logo */}
                <div className="flex flex-col flex-1">
                    <p className="text-white font-black text-3xl">NSTK</p>
                </div>

                {/* Hamburger Menu */}
                <div
                    className="hamburger-menu md:hidden block space-y-1"
                    onClick={toggleNav}
                >
                    <div className="h-1 w-6 bg-white rounded-lg"></div>
                    <div className="h-1 w-6 bg-white rounded-lg"></div>
                    <div className="h-1 w-6 bg-white rounded-lg"></div>
                </div>

                {/* List */}

            </div>
            <div
                className={
                    active
                        ? "flex flex-col md:flex-row space-y-4 md:space-y-0 md:space-x-4 bg-gray-800 w-screen p-5 transform-y-0 "
                        : "hidden md:flex md:flex-row md:space-y-0 md:space-x-4"
                }
            >
                <Link href={"/"}>
                    <p className="text-white/80 hover:text-white/90 transition-all duration-300">
                        Home
                    </p>
                </Link>
                <Link href={"/"}>
                    <p className="text-white/80 hover:text-white/90 transition-all duration-300">
                        Home
                    </p>
                </Link>
                <Link href={"/"}>
                    <p className="text-white/80 hover:text-white/90 transition-all duration-300">
                        Home
                    </p>
                </Link>
                <Link href={"/"}>
                    <p className="text-white/80 hover:text-white/90 transition-all duration-300">
                        Home
                    </p>
                </Link>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Navbar;
```